# Generating additional change addresses manually in Electrum

Tags: wallet, electrum, coldstorage

So I have an offline wallet created with Electrum. When signing transactions on the cold storage machine, I would like to be able to check that the address I'm sending the change to is actually a change address I own, however since Electrum is offline it's not up-to-date with which addresses have been used, and so the next change address that is used in the transaction hasn't actually been created yet.

For receiving addresses, I was able to manually create these addresses by running:

```
>> wallet.storage.put('gap_limit', 50)
>> wallet.storage.write()
```

in the console, which generates 50 rx addresses worth of keys.

However, this only generates *receiving* addresses, and I have funds in change addresses beyond the 6 that are generated by default. Unfortunately I haven't found how to increase this gap limit for change addresses. I've tried looking through the electrum source but haven't found anything that would let me change this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that in Electrum, you can create additional change addresses by using the console and typing:

```
for i in range(0, 100): print(wallet.create_new_address(True))
```

where 100 is the number of change addresses to create. The `True` means a change addresses is created, while `False` creates a standard receiving address. The problem is solved now :)

Comment: This did not work until I removed the word "print" from the command

Comment: @ArmanTheParman The syntax I used was for Python2, now updated for something that should work on both Py2 and 3